# Is there a possible way to fill in text from a Service or background thread?

Tags: android, service, textview

Say for the sake of example, I want to have a service that runs in the background, and every time it gets information (again for the sake of example, we'll say from a timer every minute) it populates text in the currently selected EditText field in whatever app that's currently active, is this possible?

So each time this timer goes off that's running in the background, if during that time you have a TextView active and keyboard up **on any other app** (that part is important) it fills in that text field with some arbitrary text. So in this silly example, every minute when the timer goes off, if I'm in a texting app, or on Facebook making a status, or whatever app I want to use in this example it populates the textview with "Hello" as if this background service is typing for you.

Comment: if the edit text and service are from the same app. I don't see any reason why it cannot be done.   If you want to edit text in other apps.. I dont think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would do this is by creating a new [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) that injects the text in to the EditText (or whatever is bound to it).  The InputMethodService would bind to your timing service that get commands to input the text.  This requires the user to manually select your input service (i.e. custom keyboard).

You can not do with third party keyboards as this seems like it would be pretty big security flaw to open it up like that.